# 2 AVPlayers playing the same file

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a video asset downloaded from the Internet.
I want to display this Video twice on the screen on a 2 different video layers (video playback is the same, both start and pause together).

Things I've tried:

- 2 AVPlayers the same AVAsset, but the video was downloaded twice.
- 1 AVPlayer with 2 AVPlayerLayer, only 1 video was shown on screen.

[image: 2 video players of the same video content]

The video content is the same so the video should be downloaded once.
The 2 video players should be sync.

What should I do?

Comment: Elad, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to achieve 2 video playback, and I based it on the example here, though this doesn't involve downloading the video: http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/

The source code is here: https://github.com/cezarsignori/MyVideoPlayer

Hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went over your code and notice you just load the video twice. I was looking for a way to load the video once (internet) and present it twice...

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading or streaming the video to a local server running on another thread within the same app, and this localhost server might be able to serve up 2 video streams to 2 AVPlayers.